# smtplib could not connect to socket in python with WinError 10013 on Win 7

Tags: python, sockets, windows-7, smtplib

I am trying to send email using Python's smtplib library and getting error on a Win 7 VM. I have tried it on different machines/VM's and it has worked so far, but not sure why it is not working now on this particular VM. This is the code in send_email.py-

```
import smtplib
smtp_host='smtpmailserver.mycompany.com'
s = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_host)
```

**Stacktrace-**

```
  File "C:\send_email.py", line 77, in send
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_host)
  File "C:\python3.7\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\python3.7\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\python3.7\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\python3.7\lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\python3.7\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The access to this system is blocked somewhere. It might be some firewall on the local machine, in the network or at the target machine. Since it worked from other machines it is more likely to be a local problem. No more details can be provided based on the information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and i changed the port and it worked for me

```py
s = smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_host, port 587)
```